# Using fscanf() using feof()

Tags: c, scanf, feof

Here's my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
    FILE *fp;
    int a,b;
    fp=fopen("hello.txt","r");
    while(!feof(fp)){
      fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&a,&b);
      printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
    }
}
```

My hello.txt is

```
1   2
3   4
```

My Output is

```
1   2
3   4
4   4
```

Why is my last line being printed twice. Has not fp reached EOF?

Also,the tag in stackoverflow says `Usually, when it is used, the code using it is wrong.`
What does it mean?

Thanks.

Comment: `main` should return `int` in C and C++ (your compiler may permit it, but don't do it.)

Comment: That's an awesome tag description. `eof` is indeed almost never what you want.

Comment: You are abusing `feof`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must never perform an input operation without immediately checking its result!

The following should work:

```
while (fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&a,&b) == 2)
{
    printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
}
```

This will stop at the first conversion failure or end of the file. Alternatively, you could distinguish between conversion failures (to skip the erroneous line) and end-of-file; see the documentation of `fscanf`.

Answer (score 3):

> Also,the tag in stackoverflow says `Usually, when it is used, the code using it is wrong.` What does it mean?

It means that the way the `feof()` function (and other functionality with regards to EOF in general) is used is often misunderstood and wrong. So is your code.

First, `fscanf()` doesn't always do what you think it does, and getting lines from a file is better performed using `fgets()`. **However,** if you're really inclined to use `fscanf()`, then check if it could read someting at all, else when it couldn't, you will print the variables one time more than needed. So what you should do is:

```
fp = fopen("hello.txt", "r");

while(fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &a, &b) == 2) {
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
}

fclose(fp);
```

Also, please **do use** whitespaces, your code is very hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting an extra line is that EOF isn't set until *after* `fscanf` tries to read a third time, so it fails, and you print the results anyway. This would do the sort of thing you've intended:

```
while(1){
  fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&a,&b);
  if (feof(fp))
     break;
  printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
}
```

(Note that this example does not check for errors, only for EOF)

Comment: This will break on ill-formed input [such as this one](http://pastebin.com/n1bViVDT).

Comment: @KerrekSB This is simply an example of how `feof` works, using the original code - which answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    FILE *fp;
    int a,b;
    fp=fopen("file.txt","r");
    while(fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&a,&b)==2)
    {
      printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
    }
}
```